# Exchange 2013 - Default email policy with lowercase emails?

Tags: email, exchange

I've been trying to apply a custom email address policy to our new Exchange 2013 server. By default Exchange gives users capitalized emails address. Eg - `Firstname.Surname@contoso.com`

I've done a bit of googling and I'm using the following method which is reported to work with 2007 and 2010.

```
Set-EmailAddressPolicy –identity "Default Policy" –EnabledEmailAddressTemplates "SMTP: %rAa%rBb%rCc%rDd%rEe%rFf%rGg%rHh%rIi%rJj%rKk%rLl%rMm%rNn%rOo%rPp%rQq%rRr%rSs%rTt%rUu%rVv%rWw%rXx%rYy%rZz%g.%rAa%rBb%rCc%rDd%rEe%rFf%rGg%rHh%rIi%rJj%rKk%rLl%rMm%rNn%rOo%rPp%rQq%rRr%rSs%rTt%rUu%rVv%rWw%rXx%rYy%rZz%s@contoso.com"
Get-EmailAddressPolicy | fl *appl*
```

Basically replacing [A-Z] with [a-z] for Given name (%g) and Surname (%s)

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be working - any suggestions?

Comment: Just curious why you want to do this? Email addresses aren't case sensitive...

Comment: RFC 5321 indicates they are. Perhaps exchange doesn't care, though?

Comment: Exchange does not care.  While the RFC does show it must preserve case, Exchange does ignore it.  In practice, I have never run across any system that enforces case, maybe someone else can comment on this.  But as far as Exchange goes, you shouldn't need to bother with this...  You can test this yourself with multiple case differences from the email addresses..

Comment: as a side note, since they might or might not follow the rfc, you can test adding multiple alias addresses to the users,  that might be a workaround if for some reason it did become an issue..